# Acessing nested objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, object

I need to count the number of online user in this nested object, and return the total.

I've tried this code but I am kind of lost

```
let users = {
    Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
    },
    Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
    },
    Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
    },
    Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
    }
};

function countOnline(obj) {
    let c = 0;
    for (let i in obj) {
        for (let j in i) {
            if (j.online === true) {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;

}
```

it returns 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be better to use `reduce` - iterate over the `Object.values` of the object, and add the `.online` value to the accumulator:

```js
const users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};
const usersOnline = Object.values(users).reduce((a, { online }) => a + online, 0);
console.log(usersOnline);
```

To fix your original code, you only need to loop *once*, over every property of `users`, not only every property of `users` *and* over every nested property as well (you only need the `online` property). You also need to access `obj[i]`, because `i` is a *property*, not a value:

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function countOnline(obj) {

  let c = 0;
  for (let i in obj) {
    if (obj[i].online === true) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  return c;
}
console.log(countOnline(users));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do `users[i].online` in your `if` condition. No need for nested `for`.

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function countOnline(obj) {

  let c = 0;
  for (let i in obj) {
    if (users[i].online) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  return c;

}

console.log(countOnline(users));
```

You can also shorten your code and logic as:

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function countOnline(obj) {
 var c = 0;
 Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => obj[key].online ? ++c: null);
 return c;
}

console.log(countOnline(users));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the values using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) all the users who are `online`.

```js
const users={Alan:{age:27,online:false},Jeff:{age:32,online:true},Sarah:{age:48,online:false},Ryan:{age:19,online:true}};

const count = Object.values(users).filter(a => a.online).length;

console.log(count)
```

But, I think you are better of using an array of `users` instead of having their name as key of an object. If there are more than one user with the same name, this object approach won't work